# Azure AD SSO with SAML edit Attributes & Claims - Required Claims v's optional claims

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, claims

When creating a new SSO Enterprise application, for example Palo Alto Global Protect, from the Azure gallery, you get an additional 'Required' claim added to the SAML setup called 'username'

Is it possible to create a non-gallery application and add an additional (or more) 'Required' claims versus creating them as optional claims?

I cannot seem to find out if this is possible and if not, how does a Gallery application get to add additional 'Required' claims but a non-gallery application cannot?

Best Regards,
Rich.

I have looked around the portal, googled, searched for MSGraph type solutions etc. But do not seem to find what I am looking for.